# Forking tasks workflow in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fork, workflow

I'm doing some tests to learn to fork different tasks in JavaScript as I'm new to the lenguage. I'm trying to sum every thre number group from a plain text file formated as following:

```
199
200
208
210
200
207
```

(199, 200, 208) is the first group, (200, 208, 210) is the second one, etc...

I read from the file, splited the string and got my array of strings. Now I want to do the adding in a loop that forks every iteration (in the subprocess is where the sum is being made) and print the resulting array of summed numbers.

**parent.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const readString = fs.readFileSync('depth_readings_p2.txt', 'utf8');
const readArray = readString.split('\n');

var numArrayDef = [];

for (let i = 0; i < readArray.length - 2; i++) {
    let msg = {
        i,
        readArray
    };

    let childProcess = fork('function.js');

    childProcess.send(msg);

    childProcess.on('message', (m) => {
        console.log(m);
        numArrayDef.push(m);
    });

    console.log(numArrayDef[i]);
}
```

As you see I'm sending the subprocess and object that includes the index, the array of strings and the array where the summed number will be stored. The parent process recieves the summed number and stores it in numArrayDef.

**function.js**

```js
process.on('message', (msg) => {
    let num = 0;

    if ((msg.i + 2) < msg.readArray.length) {
        num += parseInt(msg.readArray[msg.i]);
        num += parseInt(msg.readArray[msg.i + 1]);
        num += parseInt(msg.readArray[msg.i + 2]);

        process.send(num);
    }

    process.exit();
});
```

In the output I can see that the parent is receiving everything correctly, but the program isn't pushing the received values into the result array. Also, the order of execution is weird:
- First, everything in the loop but the message receiving block.
- Second, everything after the loop ends.
- Finally, the message receiving block.

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
[]
607
618
618
617
647
716
769
792
```

I know I'm missing something about forking processes, but I don't know what is it and I don't see it in the [fork documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to understand in `nodejs` is it's `asynchronious` nature, the code is not really executed in order as you have written it! (atleast, a lot of times..)

The `childProcess` is a process handle which will be returned immediatly. But the forked process itself may take some time to start. What you do, is to add a `callback` which will be executed every time, a `message` event is received. Check this code:

**parent.js**

```
let childProcess = fork('function.js');

// this line is executed immedatly after the handle is created.
// You pass a newly created function to the ".on()" function which will be 
// called everytime, the child process sends a "message" event.
// you want to understand, that you just declare an anonymious `function`
// and pass it as argument. So the executed function has actually to decide
// when to call it!.
childProcess.on('message', (m) => {
    console.log('message received in parent:', m)
    console.log('closing the process')
    childProcess.kill('SIGINT')
});


childProcess.on('exit', () => {
    console.log('child is done!')
})

childProcess.send('I will come back!')

console.log('last line reached. Program still running.')
```

**function.js**

```
process.on('message', (msg) => {

    // wait a few seconds, and return the message!
    setTimeout(() => {
        process.send(msg)
        // wait 2000ms
    }, 2000)
}
```

**output**

```
last line reached. Program still running.
message received in parent: I will come back!
closing the process
child is done!
```

##### execution order

- Fork a process and get it's handle. Code execution goes on!
- Register `callback` listeners which will be called on given events like `message` OR `exit`. These are actually `asynchronious`. You don't know when they kick in.
- log that all lines have been executed
- Some time later, the `message` listener and after it, the `exit` listener kick in.

##### your code

You code basically executes till the end (only adding handlers to a `process` handle) and will log data from `numArrayDef` which is not currently added to it. So if no element is present at `numArrayDef[5]`, it will log `undefined` per default.

##### callbacks

Since `nodejs` is single threaded per default, it's common to xecute an `asynchronious` function and pass it a `callback` (just another function) which will be executed when your called function is done!

#### The fixed code

**parent.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { fork } = require('child_process');
const { EOL } = require('os')

const readString = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');
const readArray = readString.split(EOL);

var numArrayDef = [];

for (let i = 0; i < readArray.length - 2; i++) {

    // msg building. Done instantly.
    let msg = {
        i,
        readArray
    };


    // forking a childprocess. The handle is retunred immediatly
    // but starting the process may be taking some time, and 
    // the code won't wait for it!.
    let childProcess = fork('function.js');

    // this line is executed immedatly after the handle is created.
    // You add a so 
    childProcess.on('message', (m) => {
        console.log('message recevied', m)
        numArrayDef.push(m);

        // log if all numbers are done.
        if(numArrayDef.length === readArray.length -2) {
            console.log('Done. Here\'s the array:', numArrayDef)
        }

    });

    childProcess.send(msg);
}
```

**function.js**

```js
process.on('message', (msg) => {
    let num = 0;

    if ((msg.i + 2) < msg.readArray.length) {
        num += parseInt(msg.readArray[msg.i]);
        num += parseInt(msg.readArray[msg.i + 1]);
        num += parseInt(msg.readArray[msg.i + 2]);

        process.send(num);
    }

    process.exit();
});
```

This should give you an idea. I recommend, going for some tutorials in the beginning to understand the nature of the language.

##### What you should learn about `nodejs`

- Learn what a `callback` is
- Basic understanding of `async/await` and `Promises` is a must
- You should learn, what operations are `sync` and which ones are `async`
- `Eventemitter` class is also used very often
- Learning how to handle `childprocess` or `fork` and other similar stuff, is not really required to get the base understanding of `nodejs`

#### Function  declaration

Just an addon to the syntax. These are almost exactly the same. Except that with the `arrow` function style the `this` context will be correctly applied to newly created `function`:

```
// variant1
function abc(fn) {
    // eexcute the argument which is a function. But only after
    // a timeout!. 
    setTimeout(fn, 2000)
} 

// variant2
const abc = function(fn) {
    // eexcute the argument which is a function. But only after
    // a timeout!. 
    setTimeout(fn, 2000)
}

// variant3
const abc = (fn) => {
    // eexcute the argument which is a function. But only after
    // a timeout!. 
    setTimeout(fn, 2000)
}

// call it like so:
abc(function() { 
   console.log('I was passed!!.')
})

console.log('The abc function was called. Let\'s wait for it to call the passed function!\')
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I really apreciate the time you spent on recomending me where to start learning Node. Also, everything works as intended. ^^